# What is my LAN card's MAC address?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dhcp, mac-address

EDIT: I meant wifi card, not LAN card.

I want to connect wifi devices (printer, phone, etc) to my Windows 10 laptop. I want to used a reserved DHCP address on my router for the wifi card (not LAN card), and point my devices to that IP. Using  ipconfig /all, I see a number of adapters. Which of these is my wifi card MAC (values masked)? I'm guessing it's MAC6 but want some reassurance from the community. Thanks,

```
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-xxxxxxx
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : telus

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : telus
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : MAC1-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Unknown adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : MAC2-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : MAC3-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 13:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : MAC4-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Windscribe VPN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : MAC5-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : telus
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : MAC6-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxxxxxxx:xx:xxxx(Preferred)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxxxxxxx:xx:xxxx(Preferred)(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b0fc:16f6:c49:d30d%7(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.xx(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, April 5, 2020 11:45:27 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, April 7, 2020 9:48:19 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxxxx
                                       192.168.1.254
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : xxxxxxxxx
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:568:xxxx:xxx::xx
                                       2001:568:xxxx:xx::xxx
                                       192.168.1.254
                                       75.153.171.114
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: MAC6 is your Wireless card and is currently active. Your Ethernet LAN card is currently not connected.

Answer (score 0):

> Which of these is my LAN card MAC (values masked)?

You only have a single LAN adapter, `Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection`, it's MAC address was `MAC1-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx`.  This adapter currently is not being assigned an IP Address and is currently disconnected.  The rest of your adapter other then your Broadcom device a virtual network adapters.

> I'm guessing it's MAC6 but want some reassurance from the community.

`MAC6-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx` is actually assigned to your `Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter` WiFi adapter not your network LAN adapter.

> Yes correct, I meant my WiFi adapter

In that case it would be `MAC6-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx`

Comment: If you actually want ot use your WiFi adapter, then you should edit your question, as per your question you specifically indicated you wanted to use your LAN not WiFi adapter.